# Intellij not using the right JDK, I think

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So. I was out of town for a bit about a month. Came home, booted up my computer. Windows 10 was released while I was gone, so I went ahead and updated to that. All good. And, as long as I am updating things, I should update everything. Updated intellij to the latest version. Went and grabbed that latest JDK, and uninstalled all the old ones. Now when I open up Intellij and open up a project that I know used to work, I'm getting weird 'language level' errors.

For example "Generics not supported at this language level" and "For-each loops are not supported at this language level".

Wrong JDK maybe?

My JDK is in

```
D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
```

First entry in my PATH under System variables is

```
D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin
```

JDK home path in Intellij under Project Structure is

```
D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
```

I can compile the .java file from the command line using javac

Comment: In IntelliJ's menu, go to File --> Project Structure --> Project and check on that window if your project is using the correct JDK (and the correct language level), if not, then add a new one in that same window

Comment: That was it! Had the right JDK but for some reason language level was 1.3. Go home Intellij, you're drunk.